# If log X - log Y - log Z is distributed normally, then how is X / (Y * Z) distributed?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I have three random variables, $X, Y, Z$. I know that

$$\log X - \log Y - \log Z  = \log \frac{X}{YZ} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$$

How can I recover the distribution of $\frac{X}{YZ}$? Is it as simple as $e^{\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W = \log X - \log Y - \log Z$.

So $W\sim N(0,\sigma^2)\,$.

What's the distribution of $\exp(W)$?

If you don't know what this is already, you can recover the density by [simple change of variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability).

If $Y=\phi(X)$, then:

$p_y(y) = p_x(\phi^{-1}(y)) ~ \left|\frac{d\phi^{-1}}{dy}\right|. $

Edit:

As the OP has now discerned, this means that $\exp(W)=\frac{X}{YZ}$ is $\text{lognormal}(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: So in this case, $\phi$ is $\exp$ and $E$ is $W$ and so $p_y(y) = p_W(\exp^{-1}(y)) |\frac{d \exp^{-1}}{dy}|$ ... ?

Comment: Well, $X$ is $W$ and $Y$ is $\exp(W)$. Further, you know what the inverse function of $\exp$ is already.

Comment: Oh. So exp(W) is log-normally distributed then?

Comment: Yes. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) says: "a log-normal [...] distribution is a continuous probability distribution of a random variable whose logarithm is normally distributed."